# Passing a generic type to a function with generic constraint

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a protocol with an associated Type

```
protocol ProtocolA {
  associatedType someType
}
```

Now i have two generic functions

```
func funcA<someType>(_ data:someType) {
    funcB(data) // cannot call
}

func funcB<someType:ProtocolA>(_ data:someType) {

}
```

I have been trying to call funcB from funcA, but it is not working I am getting the error

`Instance method 'funcB' requires that 'someType' conform to 'ProtocolA'`

Now i know for a fact that the Generic Type in funcA is conforming to ProtocolA. Is there anyway to also make sure that the compilers know it too ?

I cannot change the funcA method declaration to put a generic constraint as it is the requirement of another protocol.

I have tried using the `some` keyword in funcA by doing

```
var obj : some ProtocolA = data
```

However i am getting the error

`Property declares an opaque return type, but cannot infer the underlying type from its initializer expression`

Basically in short is there anyway i can call funcB from funcA without changing funcA signature, however funcB signature can be changed to whatever is required

****EDIT*****Added More Information

funcA is called by the protocl

```
protocol CommonService {
    func funcA<ModelType>(_ data:ModelType)
}

class CommonServiceImpl : CommonService {
    func funcA<someType>(_ data:someType) {
        funcB(data) // cannot call
    }

    func funcB<someType:ProtocolA>(_ data:someType) {
        //SomeCode here required that someType must implement ProtocolA
    }
}
```

ProtocolA is contained in a third party pod that cannot be changed.

*******Edit***********How i solved the problem

So thanks to @Mojtaba Hosseini in answers i got a really good idea on how to solve my problem.

I simply wrote an overloaded function in my CommonServiceProtocol

```
protocol CommonService {
    func funcA<ModelType>(_ data:ModelType)
    func funcA<ModelType>(_ data:ModelType) where ModelType:ProtocolA
}

class CommonServiceImpl : CommonService {
    func funcA<someType>(_ data:someType) {
        funcB(data) // cannot call
    }

    func funcA<someType>(_ data:someType) where ModelType:ProtocolA {
        funcB(data) // can be called
    }

    func funcB<someType:ProtocolA>(_ data:someType) {
        //SomeCode here required that someType must implement ProtocolA
    }
}
```

I mean it is not a perfect solution but given the hard dependency on an associatedType using ProtocolA in a third party pod i would say it works alright and that is one of the reasons to avoid third party dependencies as much as possible.

Comment: Can you share how are you calling funcA and what is the protocol type you're passing and protocol definition?

Comment: @NikhilJain Added more information

Comment: Let alone the compiler, you are not even convincing _me_ that `someType` in `funcA` must conform to `ProtocolA`. What if I have `class A {}`, and then did `CommonServiceImpl().funcA(A())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to also make sure that the compilers know it too?

You have to implement an overload for the `funcA` and constraint it:

```
func funcA<someType>(_ data: someType) {
    /* funcB(data) */ cannot call
    print("Not detected")

}

func funcA<someType>(_ data: someType) where someType: ProtocolA {
    funcB(data) // can call ✅
    print("Detected")
}
```

so calling `funcA("")` will result `Not detected`
but conforming to the protocol and calling the same function will result in `Detected`

```
// extension String: ProtocolA { typealias someType = String } // uncomment to see
funcA("")
```

Comment: I tried doing this technique but CommonServiceImpl in my code is still calling the first overloaded function print("not detected")

Comment: I mean i only have the method with first signature in my CommonService protocol why would then the overloaded function be called ?

Comment: maybe you should expose more of your code because I've tested with conformed and not conformed types and I see no issues

Comment: See Edit Please. Hey thanks a lot your genius idea gave me my solution. Thanks for saving my day :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I think you can match the signature of your `funcB` with `funcA`. Refer to the code below:

```
func funcA<someType>(_ data:someType) {
    funcB(data) 
}

func funcB<someType>(_ data:someType) {

}
```

As shown in the above code, you can remove the type constraint for someType in funcB.

Comment: The problem is that there is someCode in funcB that requires that someType in funcB to conform to ProtocolA

Answer (score 0):

In functionB just add a parameter that will tell the compiler the type you expect, if you really want to be sure the type is your protocol add a check :

```
func transform<T>( data : T ){
guard let  data = data as? Monster else {
        print("data is not a monster type")
        return
    }
intoMonster(Monster.self, data: data)
}

func intoMonster<T> (_ type : T.Type , data : T){
}
```

Comment: The problem is that ProtocolA in my example is in a third party Pod and using associatedType that means whenever i try to check through "as" i get the error "Protocol 'ProtocolA' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"